# Почему первая часть срабатывает, а вторая нет? List()

Tags: python

```py
def invert_array(A:list, N:int):
    B = list(A)
    for k in range(N):
        B[k] = A[N-1-k]
    A = list(B)

def test_invert_array():
    A1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    B = list(A1)
    for k in range(5):
        B[k] = A1[5-1-k]
    A1 = list(B)
    if A1 == [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]:
        print('#test1 - ok')
    else:
        print('#test1 - fail')

    A2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10]
    invert_array(A2, 8)
    if A2 == [10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]:
        print('#test2 - ok')
    else:
        print('#test2 - fail')
test_invert_array()
```

Comment: внесите ясности, пока что вообще не понятно что должно работать, а что не работает

Comment: Если код вызывать через функцию в другой функции, то он не срабатывает. Если сделать тоже самое внутри одной функции, то он сработает. Вопрос: Почему так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что, A2 является локальной переменной *test_invert_array()*.

Когда вы вызываете функцию *invert_array()*, вы передаете только копию аргумента,
а сам список не изменяется, тут можно просто вернуть изменённый список:

```
def invert_array(A:list, N:int):
    B = list(A)

    for k in range(N):
        B[k] = A[N-1-k]

    A = list(B)
    return A

def test_invert_array():
    A1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    B = list(A1)

    for k in range(5):
        B[k] = A1[5-1-k]

    A1 = list(B)

    if A1 == [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]:
        print('#test1 - ok')
    else:
        print('#test1 - fail')

    A2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10]
    A2 = invert_array(A2, 8)

    if A2 == [10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]:
        print('#test2 - ok')
    else:
        print('#test2 - fail')

test_invert_array()
```

Comment: А почему такой вариант срабатывает? `def invert_array(A:list, N:int):
    B = list(A)
    for k in range(N):
        A[k] = B[N-1-k]`

Comment: @Артур Python написан на Си, а объект списка в CPython представлен структурой, в которой находятся указатели на объекты списка. Когда вы изменяете эти объекты в цикле 'for', вы изменяете область памяти на которую ссылаются элементы вашего списка.

Comment: Cпасибо, выручили